# Right bracket not large enough in the `align` environment with split `\left[` and `\right ]' commands

Tags: amsmath

when I split `\left[` and `\right]` in the `align` environment and use `breqn` the equation doesn't compile. When I add `\left.` and `\right.` as virtual left and right delimiters, it works, but the `\right]` bracket does not have the right size.

Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{breqn}

\newcommand{\Sf}{\mathbf{S}_f}
\newcommand{\gradphi}[1]{(\nabla\phi)_{#1}}
\newcommand{\U}{\mathbf{U}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\right)_c^{n+1}  = 
        \dfrac{0.5}{\Omega_c} & \left[ \sum_f D_f \gradphi{f}^{n+1} \cdot \Sf + \sum_f D_f \gradphi{f}^n \cdot \Sf - \right. \nonumber \\ 
         & - \sum_f \U_f \phi_f^{n+1} \cdot \Sf  - \sum_f \U_f \phi_f^{n} \cdot \Sf \nonumber \\
         & \left. + S(\phi_c^n) + S(\phi_c^{n+1}) \right] + O(\delta t^2) + O(h^2) 
        \label{eq:phicrank}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

and it generates this:

[image]

How can I obtain the right size for the bracket in the `\right]` command? Thanks!

Comment: you have not specified that they should be the same size.  However it is usually best to avoid `\left\right` and use `\Biggl[`  and `\Biggr]` choosing a suitable big variant name, then the issue does not arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also *Papeeria*, that it is a tool online to write in `LaTeX`, it starts with a `\documentclass` named **article** (see the important comments of **Schrödinger's cat**). After you should read also the important comment of **@David Carlisle**: `\Biggl+(` or with `[` etc. can be used when you split a formula without mistakes. To the end I have moved `&` of the your code to have a fine alignment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}%<---Why do you use this package?

\newcommand{\Sf}{\mathbf{S}_f}
\newcommand{\gradphi}[1]{(\nabla\phi)_{#1}}
\newcommand{\U}{\mathbf{U}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \Bigl(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\Bigr)_c^{n+1} & = 
        \dfrac{0.5}{\Omega_c}\Biggl[ \sum_f D_f \gradphi{f}^{n+1} \cdot \Sf + \sum_f D_f \gradphi{f}^n \cdot \Sf \nonumber \\ 
         & - \sum_f \U_f \phi_f^{n+1} \cdot \Sf  - \sum_f \U_f \phi_f^{n} \cdot \Sf \nonumber \\
         &  + S(\phi_c^n) + S(\phi_c^{n+1}) \Biggr] + O(\delta t^2) + O(h^2) 
        \label{eq:phicrank}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I found an answere here stating that `breqn` helps with this issue, it doesn't. I have to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `\vphantom`.

```
\documentclass{article}% don't use \documentclass{minimal} see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114

\usepackage{mathtools}% loads \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{breqn} % <-don't use

\newcommand{\Sf}{\mathbf{S}_f}
\newcommand{\gradphi}[1]{(\nabla\phi)_{#1}}
\newcommand{\U}{\mathbf{U}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\right)_c^{n+1}  = 
        \dfrac{0.5}{\Omega_c} & \left[ \sum_f D_f \gradphi{f}^{n+1} \cdot \Sf + \sum_f D_f \gradphi{f}^n \cdot \Sf - \right. \nonumber \\ 
         & - \sum_f \U_f \phi_f^{n+1} \cdot \Sf  - \sum_f \U_f \phi_f^{n} \cdot \Sf \nonumber \\
         & \left. + S(\phi_c^n) + S(\phi_c^{n+1}) \vphantom{\sum_f}\right] + O(\delta t^2) + O(h^2) 
        \label{eq:phicrank}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the additional info about the other packages I am misusing. The answer with `\Biggl` and `\Biggr` seems cleaner than injecting additional `\left.` and `\right.`..